# Is it possible to snapshot an auto-generated ID document from FireStore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I am currently working on a mobile app and web app using a single firestore for my Final Year Project (Relatively new to Firestore).

When a customer registered to the application from the mobile app, the data is stored under the collection "users", a generated unique ID to represent each unique customer [Document] and then a sub-collection of "profile" and "orders" that stored their details.

Current Firestore setup after a customer have successfully registered:
[image: Current Firestore setup after a customer have successfully registered]

Right now I am trying to display the sub-collection of "Profile" in my web application. I have successfully managed to do so but I am limited to a single user.

```
created() {
        db.collection('users/FbkKmQMaGYY2gErEneImmjUMvRt1/profile').onSnapshot((snapshotChange) => {
            this.Users = [];
            snapshotChange.forEach((doc) => {
                this.Users.push({
                    key: doc.id,
                    fname: doc.data().fname,
                    lname: doc.data().lname,
                    username: doc.data().username,
                    mail: doc.data().mail,
                    phone: doc.data().phone,
                    adress: doc.data().adress,
                    img: doc.data().img,
                })
            });
        })
    },
```

My question: Is there any methods that I can use to call ALL the sub-collection 'Profile' (As seen In the picture above), so that I can displayed them in my Web Application for Administration's purposes.

Thank You for your help! :)

Comment: I'm not clear what you mean by "call ALL the generated ID".  Please edit the question to be more specific about what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: In the beginning, I thought that you had to go through a proper path to get to "profile", hence the Generated ID under Document. I apologized.

Comment: Could you edit the question to be more specific about what you're trying to do?  There is an edit link at the bottom of the question.

Comment: For future reference, what you're trying to do is "**query** for all of the documents in a subcollection".  But to be clear, are you trying to query just this one subcollection, or all subcollections with the same name, anywhere in the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show all profiles across all users, you can use a collection group query:

```
db.collectionGroup('profile').onSnapshot((snapshotChange) => {
```

*The rest of your code can remain the same.*

This will now get all documents from all collections named `profile`.

Note that there is no way to only get `profile` collections under `/users`, so you'll have to make sure your collection names are sufficiently unique/specific.

Comment: It now works as I intended! With that last bit of explanation, I have a rough idea on how Firestore works now, you have my utmost gratitude for the fast response!